# Is there a way to load files to multiple classes in java without having to call them everytime?

Tags: java

I've been writing a program for a multi story car park and I have to load in 3 separate files for the car park spaces, attendants and the cost of each zone. The problem is that I need to access them across multiple classes without having to call the .load() method every time. This causes the program to not work properly as it resets the loaded data in the class as I have 2 major classes Application and Admin that need to share this data across them. What can I do to fix this?

top level class with public static void main in it

```
public class Application {

    private Scanner scan;
    private Admin admin;
    private ZoneCost zoneCost;
    private Attendants attendants;
    private Database database;

    private Application() {
        scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        admin = new Admin();
        zoneCost = new ZoneCost();
        attendants = new Attendants();
        database = new Database();
        zoneCost.load();
        database.load();
    }
```

This class is called from the Application class

```
public class Admin {

    private Scanner scan;
    private Attendants attendant;
    private ZoneCost zoneCost;
    private Database database;

    Admin() {
        scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        attendant = new Attendants();
        zoneCost = new ZoneCost();
        database = new Database();
        zoneCost.load();
        attendant.load();
        database.load();
    }
```

As seen both classes end up calling the same .load() methods

**edit** Thanks everyone for helping me solve this problem so quickly it has saved me a considerable amount of time!

Comment: either pass them to the `admin` constructor or have a setter methods

Comment: how should I pass them to the admin constructor? @ScaryWombat

Comment: You would have to create/change your constructor to accept these objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the constructor to pass the Objects as parameters

```
public class Application {

        private Scanner scan;
        private Admin admin;
        private ZoneCost zoneCost;
        private Attendants attendants;
        private Database database;

        private Application() {
            scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            zoneCost = new ZoneCost();
            attendants = new Attendants();
            database = new Database();
            zoneCost.load();
            database.load();
            admin = new Admin(scan, zoneCost, database, attendants );
        }



    public class Admin {

        private Scanner scan;
        private Attendants attendant;
        private ZoneCost zoneCost;
        private Database database;

        Admin(Scanner scan, ZoneCost zoneCost, Database database, 
              Attendants attendant) {
            this.scan = scan;
            this.attendant = attendant;
            this.zoneCost = zoneCost;
            this.database = database;
        }
```

Comment: might as well pass `Scanner` as well

Comment: Yes, thanks! This has saved me a considerable amount of time